# iOS15, paragraphStyle can't working on SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, ios15, xcode13

In iOS15, SwiftUI introduced attributesString which I'm really excited about.
But I found that paragraphStyle can't working, but other attribute is working fine.

```
                                Text("JKL Services Information Management") { string in
                                let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                                paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byCharWrapping
                                let attributes = AttributeContainer([NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle])
                                string.setAttributes(attributes)
                                string.font = Font.system(size: 15, weight: .semibold)
                                string.foregroundColor = Constant.Theme.lightBlack
                            }
extension Text {
init(_ string: String, configure: ((inout AttributedString) -> Void)) {
    var attributedString = AttributedString(string) /// create an `AttributedString`
    configure(&attributedString) /// configure using the closure
    self.init(attributedString) /// initialize a `Text`
}
```

}

I expect words to become：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swIgv.png)
But the actual result is this：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8b47.png)

ParagraphStyle works in UIKit, why does it not work in SwiftUI?

Comment: Same for me.. I'm looking for `lineHeightMultiple` attribute but I can not make it work.

I found that `Text(multineTextHere)._lineHeightMultiple(0.5)` works, but I then get a deprecation warning.
So far, no success using the paragraph style property correctly

Comment: Did you find a way? I have same issue

Comment: _lineHeightMultiple does not work and producing an error in Xcode 15 now. Any ideas how to manage that?

Comment: Because it is defined in AttributeScopes.UIKitAttributes, but not in AttributeScopes.SwiftUIAttributes.